# Hangfire implemetation

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, hangfire

i am new to hangfire and looking for the solution which can solve the below case

1. take the data from the DB and convert this to CSV file. this should happen when ever the user insert the new record,hangfire should fire end of the day if there is new record inserted.
2. Can we deploy hangfire on the local machine and do the testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> take the data from the DB and convert this to CSV file

You can use hangfire to run any public method on any class in your application. So if you write a method which does what you want, then hangfire can call that method:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IUserRecordProcessor>(x => x.ProcessRecord());
```

> hangfire should fire end of the day if there is new record inserted

You can schedule hangfire to execute recurrent tasks (see [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html)). However, this execution is not conditional. Instead you should move the conditional logic into the code which hangfire calls:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IUserRecordProcessor>(x => x.ProcessRecordIfOneExists(), Cron.Daily);
```

> Can we deploy hangfire on the local machine and do the testing

Yes you can.

Comment: What if the server restarts or the pool application restarts?

Comment: @Daniel - even though hangfire runs in memory within an IIS worker process, it provides durable job execution. Basically jobs which are in progress if the server/app pool restarts will themselves be restarted when the application is available again. You can read more about this in the docs: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/